# Change the default date of PrimeNG schedule dynamically in Angular 5

Tags: typescript, fullcalendar, angular5, primeng

I am using PrimeNG schedule control in my Angular 6 solution. I want to change the default date dynamically but it is not reflecting. If I give the date on initial page load it is working fine. Please help me to do this. In below code you can see default date has been set on initial load as well in subscribe method but the subscribe method default date does not reflects.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { BlockUI, NgBlockUI } from 'ng-block-ui';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { BaseServiceCollection } from '../../services/booking-portal.service';
import { SharedService } from '../../services/shared.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
(window as any).jQuery = (window as any).$ = jQuery;
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'fullcalendar';
import { ENMessageConstant } from '../../shared/utils/en-constMsgs'
import { DEMessageConstant } from '../../shared/utils/de-constMsgs';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-booking-calendar',
    templateUrl: 'booking-calendar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['booking-calendar.component.css']
})

export class BookingCalendarComponent implements OnInit {
    @BlockUI() blockUI: NgBlockUI;
    loading: boolean;
    events: any[];
    header: any;
    options: any;
    defaultDate: Date;
    defaultView: String;
    selectedCalendarDate: Date;
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
    dateObject: any = {};
    validationMsgs: any = [];
    constructor(private toastrService: ToastrService, private _sharedService: SharedService,
        private authService: AuthService, private baseService: BaseServiceCollection, public datePipe: DatePipe) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this._sharedService.changeEmitted$.subscribe(
            text => {
                if (text.display == true) {
                    this.loading = true;
                    this.blockUI.start();
                    this.events = [];
                    **this.defaultDate = new Date(text.selectedDate);**
                    this.selectedCalendarDate = new Date(text.selectedDate);
                    this.baseService.getcalendarSearchResult(text).subscribe(resp => {
                        if (resp) {
                            resp['Events'].forEach(element => {
                                this.events.push(Object.keys(element).reduce((c, k) => (c[k.toLowerCase()] = element[k], c), {}));
                            });
                            this.loading = false;
                            this.blockUI.stop();
                        }
                    },
                        error => {
                            console.log(error);
                            this.loading = false;
                            this.blockUI.stop();
                        });
                }
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.loading = false;
                this.blockUI.stop();
            });
        const todaysDate = new Date();
        **this.defaultDate = todaysDate;**
        this.defaultView = "agendaWeek";

        this.header = {
            left: 'prev,next,today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        };
        const that = this;
        this.options = {
            dayNamesShort: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
            eventLimit: true,
            views: {
                month: {
                    eventLimit: 3
                }
            },
            selectable: true,
            dayClick: function (date) {
                //alert('clicked ' + date.format());
            },
            select: function (startDate, endDate) {
                that.selectRangeValidation(startDate, endDate);
                if (that.validationMsgs.length !== 0) {
                    that.showValidationMsgs(that.validationMsgs);
                    this.startDate = todaysDate;
                    this.endDate = todaysDate;
                }
                else {
                    this.startDate = startDate.format();
                    this.endDate = endDate.format();
                }
                this.dateObject = {
                    'startDate': this.startDate,
                    'endDate': this.endDate,
                    'display': false
                };
                that._sharedService.emitChange(this.dateObject);
                // alert('selected ' + startDate.format() + ' to ' + endDate.format());
            }
        };

    }
    loadEvents(event) {
        //this.events = [];
        if (this._sharedService.roomCalendareHeader) {
            const data = {
                'fromDate': event.view.start.toISOString(),
                'toDate': event.view.end.toISOString(),
                'roomCode': this._sharedService.roomCalendareHeader.roomCode,
            };
            this.loading = true;
            this.blockUI.start();
            this.baseService.getcalendarSearchResult(data).subscribe(resp => {
                if (resp) {
                    this.events = [];
                    resp['Events'].forEach(element => {
                        this.events.push(Object.keys(element).reduce((c, k) => (c[k.toLowerCase()] = element[k], c), {}));
                    });
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.blockUI.stop();
                }
            },
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.blockUI.stop();
                });
        }

    }

    selectRangeValidation(startDate, endDate) {
        this.validationMsgs = [];
        const dateToCompare = new Date();
        const selectedStartDate = new Date(startDate.format());
        const selectedEndDate = new Date(endDate.format());
        const rangeStart = moment(selectedStartDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        const rangeEnd = moment(selectedEndDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        const rangeDiff = rangeEnd.diff(rangeStart, 'days');

        if (selectedStartDate.getDate() < dateToCompare.getDate()) {
            if (this.authService.language.toUpperCase() == "DE") {
                this.validationMsgs.push(DEMessageConstant.START_DATE_BEFORE_TODAY);
            } else if (this.authService.language.toUpperCase() == "EN") {
                this.validationMsgs.push(ENMessageConstant.START_DATE_BEFORE_TODAY);
            }
            else {
                this.validationMsgs.push(DEMessageConstant.START_DATE_BEFORE_TODAY);
            }
        }
        if (rangeDiff > 0) {
            this.validationMsgs.push("Bitte wählen Sie den Bereich nur für einen Tag");
        }
    }

    showValidationMsgs(Messages) {
        for (let index = 0; index < Messages.length; ++index) {
            // this.toastrService.currentlyActive=0;
            this.toastrService.success(Messages[index], 'Alert');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there's a lot of code here. Please point us to the part which relates to your problem.

Comment: I have marked the lines with star

Comment: what is `text.selectedDate` and what is its content when the "subscribe" code executes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use below line of code to achieve :
$('.ui-widget').fullCalendar('gotoDate', this.defaultDate);

this.defaultDate is nothing but the date model I am using I am passing values at runtime in it